# Use javascript variable in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a JQuery function in which I am trying get the value of `select` field from my HTML.

```
$('.selectCurrency').change(function(){
        //alert(this.value);
        alert("{{$users["+this.value+"]->currency}}");
});
```

Its throwing error in `this.value`.

Any suggestions how I can get the value?

Comment: This is not possible. PHP runs on the server, JS on the client. The two cannot directly interact as you are attempting. To pass a JS value to PHP you would be best to make an AJAX request.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `.val()` function in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: That's not a very useful reply. I'm pretty sure it **will** work once you do it correctly.

Comment: I used it like this `alert("{{$users["+$(this).val()+"]->currency}}")` any other method you will suggest?

Comment: Yes - not using it like that. Please read the documentation that I linked - it provides you with all the information you need. `$('.selectCurrency:selected').val();`